# Symfony: 404 error on production

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, production-environment

Here's an example of a page that works perfectly fine on the dev env and returns a 404 error on the prod env

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL **/app/reporter/** was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at symfony.dev Port 80

*don't let yourself confuse by the /app/ route, this in a real route and has nothing to do with app.php*

running `php app/console router:debug --env=prod` does confirm there's no problem with router :

```
[router] Current routes
Name                                               Method Scheme Host   Path      
reporter                                           ANY    ANY    ANY  /app/reporter/
```

Of course, before posting this message, I  :

- cleared the cache, with console cache:clear --env=prod, as well as directly deleting cache files but this didnt change anything.
- double-checked mod_rewrite was on in phpinfo

Anyway, my guess is the error comes more from Apache so here's my conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName symfony.dev
    SetEnv SYMFONY__TENANT__ID "123"

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Symfony/web

#               <Directory />
#                       Options FollowSymLinks
#                       AllowOverride None
#               </Directory>

            <Directory /var/www/html/Symfony/web >
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
            </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
            <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                    AllowOverride None
                    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-symfony.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-symfony.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"

            <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
                    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
            </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

in `/var/www/html/`, there's only a symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    29 mai   13  2014 Symfony -> /home/me/path/to/symfony
```

and i didnt change anything in the default symfony `/web/.htaccess` :
*without comments for readability's sake*

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]


RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
   
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache error log confirmed the error came from there :

```
[negotiation:error] [pid 1583] [client 127.0.0.1:44590] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /var/www/html/Symfony/web/app (None could be negotiated).
```

As my understanding of Apache is seriously limited, i google the error and found this topic :
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2218-negotiation-discovered-file-s-matching-request-none-could-be-negotiated.htm

So i ended up **simply removing the MultiViews option of my vhost conf** and it solved it.

As the above give link is mentionning,

> This goes to show you how bad it is to simply enable settings when you are not sure what they do.